# How to get Chrome History & Bookmarks in Android Marshmallow (API>=23)?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser-history, android-browser, android-6.0-marshmallow

Till API Level 22 (i.e. till Lollipop), there has been a way to read History and Bookmarks from the Chrome app (as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541934/how-to-read-chrome-history-in-android)) using the permission `com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS`.

Now, in Android API=23 Marshmallow, since the entire Browser Bookmark system has been removed in Marshmallow ([changes here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)), the above method does not work anymore.

[Here is the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335175/how-to-continue-using-browser-bookmark-changes-in-android-6-0-api-23/33335488#33335488) that shows why this is not possible anymore.

In my research so far, I have not found good news. Google has definitely killed the System Bookmarks feature([here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3084) & [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2805)), question is if Chrome Browser would be exposing it in any manner?

Is there a replacement / way to read Bookmarks and History from Chrome (even Chrome specific would answer this question) going forward in Android Marshmallow?

Comment: Please do not confuse [tag:google-chrome] and [tag:google-chrome-app]

Comment: if you found out answer any time, please let me know. I've the same problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [permission READ\_HISTORY\_BOOKMARKS is not working on API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828417/permission-read-history-bookmarks-is-not-working-on-api-23)

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to the cited documentation, `com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS` is still defined by the framework, and can still be obtained by apps. Unfortunately, on Marshmallow and later, Chrome checks for a different permission, one that regular apps aren't allowed to obtain. For compatibility reasons, when that permission check inevitably fails, Chrome returns zero rows instead of throwing a `SecurityException`.

You can see the source code here:

[`query()`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/provider/ChromeBrowserProvider.java?l=348) calls [`hasReadAccess()`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/provider/ChromeBrowserProvider.java?l=652), which calls [`hasPermission("com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS")`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/provider/ChromeBrowserProvider.java?l=1199), which on API >= M ignores the permission argument and instead checks for [`com.android.chrome.permission.READ_WRITE_BOOKMARK_FOLDERS`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/AndroidManifest.xml?l=66). This permission is limited to system apps and apps signed with Google's key.

Comment: So, what does that mean? Can another application read Chrome for Android's history?

Comment: @Melab did any one find a solution for that?