# Reading Browser History in Android Marshmallow Device

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-browser

Until Lollipop, there has been a way to read the history from the Chrome app using the permission. But in Marshmallow the permission is removed. Does anyone know how to read the history on a Marshmallow device.

Comment: You can check more in this topic :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486463/how-to-get-chrome-history-bookmarks-in-android-marshmallow-api-23