# How to access chrome history and bookmarks from android code?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have read that since Android 6 the entire structure to access the browser history has been removed. 
Currently each app has to have its own content provider to give access to its history/bookmarks. 
I was wondering, does anyone know how to access the google chrome API to read history/bookmark on an android device?
(I have found posts only regarding the permissions that have to be set)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check more in this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486463/how-to-get-chrome-history-bookmarks-in-android-marshmallow-api-23