# permission READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS is not working on API 23

Tags: android

I did this on Api 18 and it works :

```
String[] proj = new String[] { BookmarkColumns.TITLE,BookmarkColumns.URL };
        Uri uriCustom = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
        String sel = BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
        Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uriCustom, proj, sel, null, null);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String title = "";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String url = "";

        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            boolean cont = true;
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
                title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
                url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL));
                Log.e("title" , title);
                Log.e("url" , url);
                // Do something with title and url
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

But on API 23 it doesn't work  I added this on Android.Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing i am error, Please add your logs here. And check if app is crashing

Comment: @AbdulWaheed on API 24 I don't see a logs a mCur is empty but I have a histry in chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

refer to this link introducing ***Android 6.0 Changes on bookmark browser behavior*** : 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

> This release removes support for global bookmarks. The
>   android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() and
>   android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() methods are now removed.
>   Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
>   permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level
>   23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use
>   the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks
>   data internally.