# How to Listen to visited url's from my app in android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, monitor, listen

I'm developing an app that shows ads as banners.

There's an option to request those ads with content URL.

If i give a URL with a content that the user is interested
in the ads will be better for the user.
My Question - how can i monitor the user's visited URL's?
Do i need an extra permission?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

You need to add into AndroidManifest.xml

For Lollipop and above

```
Cursor mCursor = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor .moveToFirst()) {
                while (mCursor .isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.v("titleIdx", mCursor 
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                    Log.v("urlIdx", mCursor 
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                    mCursor .moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

Use this you can access browsing history.

Comment: Hi,
I've tried it but all static fields of the Browser class can not be resolved.
I've checked and i have the import of the browser class.
My target and compile sdk are both 26
And the minimum is 16

Comment: See this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486463/how-to-get-chrome-history-bookmarks-in-android-marshmallow-api-23/33486978